# How to crawl a list of url in python web crawler?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, request, web-crawler

I have a list of url like this:

```
url = ['url_1','url_2', 'url_3']
```

and there are 300 elements in the list.

As their HTML structure is similar, I have written a function to crawl it and extract the information that I need:

```
def get_department_and_units_hours(url):
    res = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content, "html.parser")
    data = [item.string for item in soup.find_all('td')]
    data = data[1:]
    return data
```

Then, I iterate through the list and append the data into an array

```
department_and_units_hours = []
for item in url:
    department_and_units_hours.append(get_department_and_units_hours(item))

print(department_and_units_hours)
```

When I run it, it is no response. Just nothing happened. It can't print out the content of the array.

Error message:
[image]

I want to ask why the problem occurs and how to fix it? I really have no idea about it.

Comment: print the data returned from `get_department_and_units_hours()`? Are you sure this is working?

Comment: It should be ```get_department_and_units_hours(item)```, where item is the element in the url list.
sorry for the typo.

Comment: are you sure 'get_department_and_units_hours` is returning what it should?

Comment: also, could you share the url you are trying to scrape?

Comment: Yes, I sure the function return the data correctly. I can ``print(get_department_and_units_hours(url[i]))``, where i is the index of the element, and it works very well

Comment: I think the for loop is the problem, when I stop the program, it shows me the error, I have added it in the question.